# Sorting linked list contents in c alphabetically for movie titles

Tags: c, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a linked list of movie titles alphabetically in c , but I can't figure it out. This is what I have so far:

```
ReviewNode *sortReviewsByTitle(ReviewNode *head)
{
    char tempTitle[MAX_STR_LEN];
    ReviewNode *p = NULL;
    ReviewNode *temp = NULL;
    p = head;
    while (p!= NULL){
        temp = p;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            if(strcmp(temp->review.movie_title, temp->next->review.movie_title) > 0){
                strcpy(tempTitle, temp->review.movie_title);
                strcpy(temp->review.movie_title, temp->next->review.movie_title);
                strcpy(temp->next->review.movie_title, tempTitle);
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        p = p ->next;
    }
    return head;
```

one of my test cases: sorts: c, b, a and returns b, a, c

Comment: Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please explain why you are sorting a linked list by copying contents of nodes around. The point of a linked list is NOT to do that and do pointer manipulation instead. In this special case of strings, you are running many risks relating to different lengths; admittedly not for your example of three equally long "a", "b", "c" - but the problems are going to find you sooner or later...

Comment: You are comparing `*temp` and `*temp->next` You should instead compare  `*p` and `*temp` And, you could rewrite your `while` loops into `for()`loops, saving 3 lines, and avoiding a lot of possible errors.

Answer (score 2):

Insteand of using `strcpy` why not simply move the node's pointers? If it is a singly-linked list you'll need a `before` node that is the previous one to the `temp` node, so when you do `temp = temp->next` you first do `before = temp`. This is how you would do with a doubly-linked node:

```
if (strcmp(/*...*/) > 0) {
    ReviewNode *swap = temp->next;
    temp->next = swap->next;
    swap->prev = temp->prev;
    swap->next = temp;
    temp->prev = swap;
}
```

This way you don't have to copy the strings around which might take much longer than simply moving the nodes around. A good way to know how to move these links around is to grab a pencil and a piece of paper and simulate the list being sorted. It takes time but you end up learning a lot from it!

Without much more information its hard to know what problems you are facing. Good luck!